# How to get arduino to always be connected as /dev/ttyUSB0 and with chmod 0777?

Tags: usb, linux

I've got Debian 10 as OS and for a Project, I need my arduino to always be connected as /dev/ttyUSB0, not any other ttyUSB-number, and I need it to be connected with the 0777 rights for a script to work.

I've read some things about udev, but nothing I tried yet worked.

I tried creating

/etc/udev/rules.d/51-my_usb_device

with the content

SUBSYSTEM=="tty", MODE="0777", KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"

but it does not work, even after reboot (like nothing changed). I must admit though that I do not really understand udev.

How to do this?

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/making-your-boards-unique-linux

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered not trying to force ttyUSB0 but instead creating a symlink to whatever tty is assigned? Your software then just uses the symlink.

A problem with forcing a particular tty is what if you boot without the Arduino but another device is attached? You then need to convince the other device to skip ttyUSB0.

If you would consider a symlink then something like:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7523", SYMLINK+="arduino"
```

might get you started. Check the VID and PID using `lsusb` or similar. To set permissions as well you can use e.g. `MODE="0777"` as you already have.

There is an example at https://wiki.debian.org/udev that might give more background.